# Is is possible to redefine a function with more specific generics?

Tags: typescript

I have this function defined (from a library):

```
declare function originalAction<T extends StringType, P = undefined, M = undefined>(type: T, payload?: P, meta?: M): PayloadMetaAction<T, P, M>;
```

I would like to get a more specific version of this function to use in my code, where `M` is an instance of `ActionMetaType`.

At the moment I am doing this:

```
export const action = (type: string, payload?: any, meta?: ActionMetaType) =>
  originalAction(type, payload, meta)
```

But this creates a new function, which is not optimal.

Is it a way to export my custom action that is just a more-specifically typed alias of `originalAction`?

`PayloadMetaAction` is not exported by the library I am using, so I can not use it to manually redefine the interface for my `action`.

Answer (score 2):

The original generic function is able to act as any of the various possible specific functions you get if you choose values for the type parameters.  So the generic function is like an intersection of all possible specific function types.  By picking just one specific type, you're picking just one constituent of that intersection and forgetting about all the others... that is, widening the type.

And widening the type of a value is always safe.  You can do it by assigning the value to a variable of the wider type, like this:

```
const action: (type: string, payload?: any, meta?: ActionMetaType) => 
  PayloadMetaAction<string, any, ActionMetaType> = originalAction;
```

In this case `action` is not a new function, but the same function as `originlAction` being seen as the wider type that only accepts a `meta` parameter of `ActionMetaType`.

As for this:

> `PayloadMetaAction` is not exported by the library I am using, so I can not use it to manually redefine the interface for my action

If the library is exporting the function but not its (generic) return type, I'm not sure what you can do without more information.  You can play games like this:

```
const _action = (type: string, payload?: any, meta?: ActionMetaType) =>
  originalAction(type, payload, meta)

export const action: typeof _action = originalAction;
```

where you don't use `_action` but do refer to its type `typeof _action`... but I don't know if that will work without more explicit information about the library.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @jcalz ! I tried this approach but it is not working, the library I use is doing complex stuff with the types and this breaks things as it seems to change the return type to something that is not accepted. I think the issue is not with TS itself.More details here: https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions/issues/70

Comment: If something's not working you should post a [mcve] if you want more help.  The GitHub issue you linked doesn't seem to provide enough information for me to understand where the problem is.  Anyway, good luck!